# Is it possible to run something like git blame -L 1,5 README.md with GitHub's API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am seeing Gists all over the place that show a very basic example of a GraphQL query that passes a file path as a parameter and then the query returns the starting and ending lines, plus the commit hashes of such.

Something like this https://gist.github.com/davidcelis/dd85095ac46e159b9efe420687aaa7e9

Is it possible to pass a starting line and an ending line as a parameter? "I want to obtain the commit hashes of lines 1 to 5 in README.md"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only field for [Blame inside Commit](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#commit) is... `path`.

So you cannot add a BlameRange as parameter. You can only get ranges as a result of a query.

Comment: Fair enough answer! Ty.